# Implement HttpRequestRetryHandler and RequestBuilder in httpclient5

Tags: java, httpclient, apache-httpclient-5.x

I plan to update my project to use httpclient5.
After that I recognized in httpclient5 (5.0, 5.01 and 5.0.2), they don't have the class HttPRequestRetryHandler and RequestBuilder anymore.
Is there any way or update to not use these class in http5, or do we have some alternatives with the same functions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Use `org.apache.hc.client5.http.HttpRequestRetryStrategy` instead.
2. Use `org.apache.hc.core5.http.io.support.ClassicRequestBuilder` with the classic transport and `org.apache.hc.core5.http.nio.support.AsyncRequestBuilder` with the async transport.

Generally this resource might prove useful when migrating from Apache HttpClient 4.5.x to Apache HttpClient 5.x

https://ok2c.github.io/httpclient-migration-guide/

Comment: It works flawlessly, except the ClassicRequestBuilder doesn't have the setConfig(method). Do you have any suggestion, ok2c?

Comment: Please use `HttpClientContext#setRequestConfig` instead